# Pagination passing post data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pagination

I'm working on php pagination - its a form that has a few inputs to pull from a DB. Form posts to same page.

I have everything working, filling out form and the results are displayed with the correct pagination links.

**ISSUE:** I click on the links to go to the next page and the results clear out.

**EDIT:** I may have to rethink this. Perhaps I could store the post data in the session or refactor with ajax. Seems that because I have my code tucked into the if submit condition it wont run when the page is changed.

Going from

```
?page=1&submitter=John
```

to

```
?page=2&submitter=John
```

resets and clears out the page.

I'm not completely sure how to accomplish this part. (Pulls hair out)

**PHP**

```php
$sub_id         = $_POST['sub-id'] ?? '';
$submitter      = $_POST['submitter'] ?? '';
$sub_start_date = $_POST['sub-start-date'] ?? '';
$sub_end_date   = $_POST['sub-end-date'] ?? '';
$sub_policy     = $_POST['sub-policy'] ?? '';
$total_results = array();
$paginated_results = array();
$total_rows = 0;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    unset($_POST['submit']);

    $errors = error_check();


    // filter out empty post data. Maybe right?

    $filtered_data = array_filter($_POST, function ($value) {
            return $value !== '';
    });


    $query_string = http_build_query($filtered_data);



    try {
        // Set up pagination
        $per_page = 10;

        // Get current Page
        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; // Current page number

        // Calculate the offset for the current page
        $start_from = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

        // Start Main SQL Query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE 1=1";

        // Create array to hold inputs to bind to the statement
        $inputs = array(
            'submission_id' => $sub_id,
            'submitter' => $submitter,
            'policy' => $sub_policy,
            'sub_start_date' => $sub_start_date,
            'sub_end_date' => $sub_end_date
        );

        $where_clause = array();

        // Add key=>values from the inputs array
        // to the where_clause array; first skip
        // over the start and end dates because
        // they require a different wording
        foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                if ($key === 'sub_start_date' || $key === 'sub_end_date') {
                    continue; // Skip the start and end dates for now
                } else {
                    $where_clause[] = "$key = :$key";
                }
            }
        }

        // Add the date range condition using BETWEEN
        if (!empty($sub_start_date) && !empty($sub_end_date)) {
            $where_clause[] = "creation_dt BETWEEN :sub_start_date AND :sub_end_date";
        }

        // Now add the where_clause to the query
        if (!empty($where_clause)) {
            $query .= " AND " . implode(" AND ", $where_clause);
        }

        // Count the total number of rows
        $count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows FROM submissions WHERE 1=1";
        if (!empty($where_clause)) {
            $count_query .= " AND " . implode(" AND ", $where_clause);
        }

        $count_stmt = $db->prepare($count_query);

        foreach ($inputs as $param => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                if ($param === 'sub_start_date' || $param === 'sub_end_date') {
                    $count_stmt->bindValue(':' . $param, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                } else {
                    $count_stmt->bindValue(':' . $param, $value);
                }
            }
        }
        $count_stmt->execute();
        $total_rows = $count_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['total_rows'];

        $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $per_page);


        // Offset base page Limit total records per page
        $query .= " LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset";

        // Prepare the query
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

        // Bind the values to the named placeholders
        foreach ($inputs as $param => $value) {
            if (!empty($value)) {
                if ($param === 'sub_start_date' || $param === 'sub_end_date') {
                    $stmt->bindValue(':' . $param, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                } else {
                    $stmt->bindValue(':' . $param, $value);
                }
            }
        }

        // Calculate the limit and offset
        $stmt->bindValue(':limit', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':offset', $start_from, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $rows_found = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $paginated_results = $rows_found;
        $results = true;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log("There are errors");
        array_push($errors, "Something went wrong, please try again." . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**SMARTY**

```html
   <div class="results_wrap">
      <table class="search_results_table">
        <tr>
          <th class="t-header">Id</th>
          <th class="t-header">Submission Id</th>
          <th class="t-header">Date</th>
          <th class="t-header">Policy</th>
          <th class="t-header">Submitter</th>
        </tr>
          {foreach $paginated_results as $paginated_result}
            <tr>
              <td>{$paginated_result['id']}</td>
              <td>{$paginated_result['submission_id']}</td>
              <td>{$paginated_result['creation_dt']}</td>
              <td>{$paginated_result['policy']}</td>
              <td>{$paginated_result['submitter']}</td>
            </tr>
          {/foreach}
      </table>
    </div>
    {/if}
    <div class="pagination">
        {for $x=1 to $total_pages}
            {add_param assign=self name="page" value=$x}
            {if $x == $page}
              <a class="active_page" href="{$self}&amp;{$query_string}">{$x}</a>
            {else}
              <a class="paginate" href="{$self}&amp;{$query_string}">{$x}</a>
            {/if}
        {/for}
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think `:limit` can not be passed as a bound value, say as prepared statement. Also the syntax is `LIMIT <offset>,<length>`.

Comment: Did I misread that? A little ways down the page it says it can be bound. You're right boundParam. thank you for the help!
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Why are you using POST in this case? POST is usually used if you are actually modifying some database entries or something. GET is used to... well... GET data.

Comment: Using the session for this is not such a good idea; the user would not be able to paginate two _different_ selections in two different browser tabs correctly. If you want to use POST parameters - then you need to make your pagination _links_ into submit buttons in a form, that transports the rest of the parameters via hidden fields. Or you switch to GET to begin with - which would also have the advantage, that you will get URLs that are bookmarkable/ sharable with other users.

Comment: Switching from POST to GET worked. This was my first go at retrieving records from a DB. Many thanks to the advice!